# Display tr/td element only if dropdown element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to hiding a tr/td  and only displaying by select the correct tr/td in a dropdown.

I tried following, but is not working. Maybe someone see what is wrong. Thank you in advance for the help.

Dropdown:

```
<tr>    
    <td>Dropdown_TEST:</td>
    <td><select required id=" Dropdown_TEST">
               <option value=""></option>
               <option  class="cont" value="TEST 1"> TEST 1</option>
               <option class="cont_1"  value=" TEST 2"> TEST 2</option> 
         </select> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Example 1:

```
<tr class="display">    
    <td>TEST:</td>
    <td><input id="pl" name="pl" type="text" maxlength="50" size="50"></td>
</tr>
```

Example 2

```
<tr class=" display_1"> 
   <td>TEST 2:</td>
   <td><select required id="platt">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="yes, is working"> yes, is working </option>
            <option value="no is not working"> no is not working </option>
       </select> 
   </td>
</tr>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.cont).length)
        $('.display).show();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.cont_1).length)
        $('.display_1).show();
});

</script
```

Thank you so much for your help and support.

Comment: I don't see any element with class cont_1

Comment: HI Ryan, yes, thank you i correct it... but this was not the error any idea? thx.

Comment: Your selectors are invalid.  You are missing the closing `'` on all of them.  Also as a side note, you do not need multiple document ready's.

Comment: have you tried `if($('.cont:selected')) { [...] }` ?

Comment: @Stef Added an answer below which I think will accomplish what you are going for.

Comment: @RyanWilson thx see comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //evaluate when the dropdown changes
  $('#Dropdown_TEST').on('change', function(){
    //reset everything to visible
    $('.display, .display_1').show();

    //if you do not have a value, ignore
    if (this.value.trim()) {
      //hide first display if it should not be shown
      if (this.value !== 'TEST 1') {
        $('.display').hide();
      }

      //hide the second display if it should not be shown
      if (this.value !== 'TEST 2') {
        $('.display_1').hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Dropdown_TEST:</td>
    <td>
      <select required id="Dropdown_TEST">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option class="cont" value="TEST 1"> TEST 1</option>
        <option class="cont_1" value="TEST 2"> TEST 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="display">
    <td>TEST:</td>
    <td><input id="pl" name="pl" type="text" maxlength="50" size="50"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="display_1">
    <td>TEST 2:</td>
    <td>
      <select required id="platt">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="yes, is working"> yes, is working </option>
        <option value="no is not working"> no is not working </option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a shot and I'm going off of your post, which to me is not real clear, but here it goes:

```
//Guessing this is the drop down that makes one row or another visible
<tr>    
    <td>Dropdown_TEST:</td>
    <td><select required id=" Dropdown_TEST">
               <option value=""></option>
               <option  class="cont" value="TEST 1"> TEST 1</option>
               <option class="cont2"  value=" TEST 2"> TEST 2</option>  
         </select> 
    </td>
</tr>

//So in your script, instead of checking for the existence of options with classes
//cont and cont_1, add an event handler to the above drop down change event
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Dropdown_TEST').on('change', function(){
         if($(this).find('option:selected').text().trim() === "TEST 1"){
             //If TEST 1 is the drop down option, show tr with class display
             //and hide tr with class display_1
             $('.display').css('display', 'block');
             $('.display_1').css('display', 'none');
         }else if($(this).find('option:selected').text().trim() === "TEST 2"){
             //If TEST 2 is the drop down option, show tr with class display_1
             //and hide tr with class display
             $('.display').css('display', 'none');
             $('.display_1').css('display', 'block');
         }else{
             //else hide both trs or else comment these out if you don't want to hide them
             $('.display').css('display', 'none');
             $('.display_1').css('display', 'none');
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan. Dropdown, Example 1 and Example 2 are part of a Form. So what i'm trying to do is... if i chooos on the dropdown the value TEST 1 will only the output Example 1 will be showing and Example 2 not

Comment: @Stef, that is what my answer does...not sure why you gave the accepted answer and an upvote to the person who answered after me???

Comment: when i wrote you i didn't see the answer from the other person. after i text you yes.. sorry for that